# Bring REVIT Areas to FORGE VIEWER

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api

I wanted to know if there is some quick way to have the 'Revit Area items' available at the Viewer, via the self Viewer API or Model Derivatives preferably, or any solution that you have in mind of course will be aprettiated too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To see the Revit area in Forge Viewer, you will need to include the [area plan](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Revit-Analyze/files/GUID-35C933A7-8ABF-466D-8E01-8571B7BDC03F-htm.html) view in either the active view set of the [Publish Settings](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/simplecontent/content/publishing-settings-revit-for-bim-360.html).

Here are snapshots of my research.
[image]
[image]